# Crawler headers

Tags: http-headers, web-crawler

I'm creating a simple crawler that will scrape from a list of pre-defined sites. My simple question: are there any http headers that the crawler should specifically use? What's considered required, and desirable to have defined?

Answer (score 2):

You should at least specify a custom user agent (as done here by [StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/protocol/httpclient/HttpProtocol.java#L87)) so that the webmasters of the sites you are crawling can see that you are robot and contact you if needed.

More importantly, your crawler should follow the robots.txt directives, throttle the frequency of requests to the sites, etc... which leads me to the following question : why not reuse and customise an existing open source crawler like StormCrawler, Nutch or Scrapy instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I've only used Scrapy, but it takes a long time to set up. Doing stuff with request and cheerio in node.js seems both quicker and easier to customize to fit the use case at hand.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to tell who you are and your intentions, and how to get a hold of you. I remember from running a site and looking at the access.log for Apaceh that the following info actually had a  mission (as some of the ones listed in StromCrawler code):

1. Agent name - just the brand name of your crawler
2. Version of your agent software - If issues with earlier versions of the agent, good to see that it's an evolved version
3. URL to info about agent - A link to an info-page about the crawler. More info on purpose, technical buildup etc. Also a place to get in contact with the people behind a bot.

If you check out [Request fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields), you'll find two of interest: `User-Agent` and `from`. The second one is the email address, but last I checked it doesn't appear in the access.log for Apache2. The User-Agent for [automated agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format_for_automated_agents_.28bots.29) should contain name, version and URL to a page with more info about the agent. It also common to have the word "bot" in your agent name.